# Col being 100% affects message box size

Tags: html, css, col

I made my col 100% after getting to 900px of the browser's width and this happened [Problem image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrM5i.jpg)... So I've tried reducing the width of the box but it didn't work. Pls is there any other way to fix this?

Comment: Can you please post the code you currently have? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I've already fixed it with a margin to the right of 600px. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add `padding` to the column, and reduce the `width` to perhaps 80%.

Furthermore, `margin-right`, could also help with the formatting.

Comment: Padding solved it 50%, but it did not reduce the width of the box.
So i tried giving it some margin to the right and that worked
Thank you

Comment: Please consider marking this right, if this helped you